# css / javascript transition: my css transitions not working with the gallery if image quickly changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

javascript / html snippet:

```
<script>

        var backgroundImages = new Array(); // create an array holding the links of each image
        var backgroundImages = [
            "style/images/bg0.png",
            "style/images/bg1.png",
            "style/images/bg2.png",
            "style/images/bg3.png",
            "style/images/bg4.png",
            "style/images/bg5.png",
            "style/images/bg6.png",
        ];

        var ImageCnt = 0;

        function nextImage(direction) // this should take into account the current value (starts at 3) and determines whether a higher or lower value should be returned based on the direction
        {
            ImageCnt = (ImageCnt + (direction == "left" ? backgroundImages.length-1 : 1)) % backgroundImages.length;
            document.getElementById("body-1").style.background = "url('"+backgroundImages[ImageCnt]+"')";//put's the new background together for rendering by using the returned value from nextImage()
        }

</script>

<div class="body-1" id="body-1"><!-- begin body 1 :: this will hold the topmost image slider -->
    <div class="transition" id="trans-left" onclick='nextImage("left");return false;'><!-- begin transition left :: this will take advantage of rotation to use the same loaded image for both the left and right arrows -->
        <img src="images/transition.png"/>
    </div><!-- end transition left -->
    <div class="transition" id="trans-right" onclick='nextImage("right");return false;'><!-- begin transition right :: this will take advantage of rotation to use the same loaded image for both the left and right arrows -->
        <img src="images/transition.png"/>
    </div><!-- end transition right -->
</div>
```

And here is the involved CSS, which is relatively simple:

```
.body-1
{
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 470px;
    background-color: #ebf6f7;
    background-image: url('images/bg3.png');
    background-size: 100% 470px;
    transition: background-image 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The image cycles through my image array properly, but the transition does not take effect if the user transitions more quickly than the transition has time to be completed.

Does anyone have an idea for a fix here?

Comment: Haven't heard of JQuery Slide Shows ?

Comment: jt0dd, Array elements should be enclosed within braces i.e. '{}' not square braket i.e. '[]'. Isn't it?

Comment: @AmitRanjan This is a project that must be my own scripting.

Comment: @RajeshPaul The image cycles through as it should, so I dont think this matters either way

Comment: @jt0dd , then kool. If you wish, keep while development , never never try to re-invent the wheel, until and unless it is utmost required. Each and every alternatives are available over here, Google and StacOverflow

Comment: @jt0dd, Check the solution I have given. Check the link [fiddle_demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh38/4g3FP/). Ur syntax is all right regarding the array. Sorry for my previous comment.

Comment: @jt0dd, if u think my answer is useful then cast an upvote please. I did upvoted ur question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **solution**. in the [**fiddle_demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh38/4g3FP/)

I have used **`setTimeout()`** of JavaScript to **elapse the slide-tranisition time**(i.e. **2s**) here while executing the **`nextImage()`**. Along with that a **status**-variable to keep track whether the time required for a tranisition has elapsed or not. If not then **`onclick`** cannot call **`nextImage()`**. That is the **trick**.

use this code-

```
<script>
    status=0;
        var backgroundImages = new Array(); // create an array holding the links of each image
        var backgroundImages = [
            "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1nZVCpqazRlfrHxxFkCegMnVN5YQcwd9wucAwCbPlyHdRcuIw51Y877-H",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQfCDIMnT0a9eLueandJ127Cmo-ZXpBhch83tmhWfAu5EA4uZZimnIv9c0",
            "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6KEBXB2afWZN9EimiM7rf-ap8M8I8gxc02N9hyS0L98WxG6EVwoLfGhU",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNdmylPtmOnRNG14qWjBhPGu949eld0JnUqgFdREQVEnH8TxvTQnlGQQw",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSLS_jeHM1jbWzgHbVZJbEBWcrfnI1gbMjsqsS1d4Joxm6svO5_a90Y8wnE",
            "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrEES7eyR-rTSJeak-18JrCx-IKF1QJtzzlhihiLG5hwHQ-YT90prT-mc",
            "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT69YiOi2muMfySs4l-c7kIN-xoM_iJKWVh4sOKTOXmLSQkh_ZyfnPLe5g",
        ];

        var ImageCnt = 0;

        function nextImage(direction) // this should take into account the current value (starts at 3) and determines whether a higher or lower value should be returned based on the direction
        {
            status=1;
            ImageCnt = (ImageCnt + (direction == "left" ? backgroundImages.length-1 : 1)) % backgroundImages.length;
            document.getElementById("body-1").style.background = "url('"+backgroundImages[ImageCnt]+"')";//put's the new background together for rendering by using the returned value from nextImage()
            setTimeout('status=0;',2000);
        }

</script>

<div class="body-1" id="body-1"><!-- begin body 1 :: this will hold the topmost image slider -->
    <div class="transition" id="trans-left" onclick='if(status==0){nextImage("left");return false;}'><!-- begin transition left :: this will take advantage of rotation to use the same loaded image for both the left and right arrows -->
        <img src="images/transition.png"/>
    </div><!-- end transition left -->
    <div class="transition" id="trans-right" onclick='if(status==0){nextImage("right");return false;}'><!-- begin transition right :: this will take advantage of rotation to use the same loaded image for both the left and right arrows -->
        <img src="images/transition.png"/>
    </div><!-- end transition right -->
</div>
```

I think this solves ur problem.

Comment: This is an excellent to the solution, however, it seems like this will still keep the user from transitioning if they want for some reason, to advance through them quickly. This would not be a problem really, however, it's possible that my professor might deduct for a solution that involves delaying the user. Maybe I interpreted this incorrectly and it does not prohibit the user? Your js fiddle doesnt appear ot be working properly

Comment: @jt0dd, yes, you can definitely ask ur user to enter their choice of holding through the transition time or advance to next slide. Depending on their choice u may change the following statement-

`setTimeout('status=0;',2000);`

to

`setTimeout('status=0;',0);`

And for that u have to use a variable for that in place of `2000`.

Comment: I decided to evade the issue of needing any delay by using the format here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905208/javascript-css-cycling-image-content-gallery-first-small-part-of-my-script

Comment: @jt0dd There is a slight portion of one of the previous/next button at the **left hand top corner** of the **jsfiddle_demo**. I had to try to click on the button. That positioning depends upon your css. U can click on it if u try.

Comment: That format uses multiple divs stacked to allow for separate transitions to occur, so for example, 2-3 divs might transition at once if the user clicks them quickly, but it will not need to be delayed or look badly. The beginning of this script just has some sort of error

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is prevent an animation happening if one is already in progress.
Two ways of doing this:

1. something like if( ! animation is happening ){  } wrapped around your javascript.
2. disable the next.prev buttons while an animation is happening.

I could tell you how to do this in jQuery but I'd struggle to do it in native javascript but the principle is sound...

Comment: This makes sense and would solve most of the problem, however it's prohibitive to the user a tad bid, and this might be frowned on by some. I have fixed my original question here, but it has lead of course, to new problems :)